# Preventing NAs recoded as 1 in user-written function

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
> res5
          A        B
 1   (75,89.3] (4,14.9]
 2  (96.4,100] (-Inf,0]
 3        <NA>     <NA>
 4      (0,75] (4,14.9]
 5        <NA>     <NA>
 6 (89.3,96.4] (4,14.9]


> dput(res5)
structure(list(A = structure(c(3L, 5L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L), .Label = c("(-Inf,0]", 
"(0,75]", "(75,89.3]", "(89.3,96.4]", "(96.4,100]", "(100, Inf]"
), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(3L, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("(-Inf,0]", 
"(0,4]", "(4,14.9]", "(14.9,68]", "(68, Inf]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I apply my function to this dataframe, I have the following result:

```
res6<-lapply (names(res5), function (x){as.numeric(!res5[,x] %in% head(levels(res5[,x]), 2))})


> res6
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

My function works great except it coded all NA values as "1". How do I prevent my function doing it and leave NAs as NAs? 
I suspect that the point is in transorming "NA" to NA (without quotes), I tried

```
  within (res5 , "NA"==NA)
```

and it did not help. 
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you use in.na to check for NAs: see the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res6 <- lapply (names(res5), function (x){
  res <- as.numeric(!res5[,x] %in% head(levels(res5[,x]), 2)) 
  ifelse(is.na(res5[,x]),NA,res)
  })
```

An alternative:

```
res6 <- lapply (names(res5), function (x){
  as.integer(as.logical(as.integer(!res5[,x] %in% head(levels(res5[,x]), 2)) * as.integer(res5[,x])))  
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Roland, but this solution unfortunately requires too much memory - R crashes. My real dataframe is rather large.

Comment: I've added an alternative, but don't know if it needs less memory. You might need to consider other possibilities (e.g., using `data.table` might help somewhat).